# sendData (lib AsyncSocket) just before iPhone quit

Tags: iphone, macos, asyncsocket

I have an iPhone application that send datas via wifi on my mac. I would like to send a logout message to my mac when I quit the iPhone app.
I tried to send it on the  :

**-applicationWillTerminate** methode

but it seems that the application shut down my service before. How and where can I send my message just before the exit ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-applicationWillTerminate:` is the best possible place that for putting on-exit code for iPhone apps. But your app will be force-killed anyway if the termination takes too long.

Your server could just invalidate the session if there's no response for too long.

Comment: Ok so just implement a NSTimer that look if my iPhone send a message (for example 0) every second. If during 5 sec I have not this message I cut off my connexion.
But how do you restart properly a server connexion with AsyncSocket ?

Comment: @Pierre: I don't know much about AsyncSocket, but you could just reconnect like how the connection was created when the app starts...